# Custom Search box for Google map

Tags: html, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am developing web application using Google map JavaScript version. I need to add search box like Google Search box which is on Google map (like attached image). And I need to search custom places which are on my database.

[image]

If it is possible, how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This example adds a search box to a map, using the Google Place Autocomplete feature. People can enter geographical searches. The search box will return a pick list containing a mix of places and predicted search terms.

```
function initialize() {

  var markers = [];
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var defaultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
  new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8902, 151.1759),
  new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8474, 151.2631));
map.fitBounds(defaultBounds);

// Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
var input = /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(
  document.getElementById('pac-input'));
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(
/** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(input));

// Listen for the event fired when the user selects an item from the
// pick list. Retrieve the matching places for that item.
google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', function() {
var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

for (var i = 0, marker; marker = markers[i]; i++) {
  marker.setMap(null);
}

// For each place, get the icon, place name, and location.
markers = [];
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
for (var i = 0, place; place = places[i]; i++) {
  var image = {
    url: place.icon,
    size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
  };

  // Create a marker for each place.
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    icon: image,
    title: place.name,
    position: place.geometry.location
  });

  markers.push(marker);

  bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
}

map.fitBounds(bounds);
});

// Bias the SearchBox results towards places that are within the bounds of the
// current map's viewport.
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
var bounds = map.getBounds();
searchBox.setBounds(bounds);
});
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: thanks for reply. actually i want to get search places from my database not Google .. so how to get search result from my database? In this example i cant get result data from Google.

Comment: If you want retrieve places from your database, for that you have to write database connection code. After that you have to retrieve palces using autocomplete search box.